# SQL: whats wrong with this "where if" query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've selected table: **A1** and joined **A2** to **A1**, AND **A3** joined to **A2**. 

**A1**.level and **A2**.level always not null
**A3**.level means that that joined row is null.
**A1**.level is bigger then **A2**.level.
IF **A3**.level is smaller than **A2**.level or setted to (NULL)
SO, I need result like this

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ A1.level ║ A2.level ║ A3.level ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║        3 ║        2 ║ 1        ║
║       14 ║       10 ║ 5        ║
║       15 ║       13 ║ (NULL)   ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

I've tried to write statement like this

```
SELECT A1.level, A2.level, A3.level
FROM A1,
LEFT JOIN A2 ON A1.parentID = A2.id
LEFT JOIN A3 ON A2.parentID = A3.id
WHERE A1.level > A2.level
      AND A2.level > A3.level OR A3.level IS NULL
```

but it doesn't work. How to write IF (or CASE) statment for this? Thanks

Comment: `SELECT * FROM A1.level, A2.level, A3.level
FROM A1`  or  `SELECT  A1.level, A2.level, A3.level
FROM A1` ???

Comment: Define "it doesn't work" - an error message? Wrong results? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add parentheses:

```
SELECT A1.level, A2.level, A3.level
FROM A1
JOIN A2  -- no need for LEFT JOIN
  ON A1.parentID = A2.id
LEFT JOIN A3
  ON A2.parentID = A3.id
WHERE (A1.level > A2.level)
      AND (A2.level > A3.level OR A3.level IS NULL)
```

Otherwise the order of precedence is:

```
NOT - AND - OR
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Use parenthesis;

```
SELECT A1.level, A2.level, A3.level
FROM A1,
LEFT JOIN A2 ON A1.parentID = A2.id
LEFT JOIN A3 ON A2.parentID = A3.id
WHERE 
    (A1.level is not null and A2.level is not null) and --A1.level and A2.level always not null
    (A1.level > A2.level) and --A1.level is bigger then A2.level.
    (A2.level > A3.level OR A3.level IS NULL) --A3.level is smaller than A2.level or setted to (NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a copy/paste error (you specify the field to select after the from) and put a comma at the wrong place (before your first join).
Furthermore, you need parenthesis for your condition concerning A3.
I personally don't think that a `IF` statement is required in this case.

```
SELECT A1.level, A2.level, A3.level 
FROM A1
LEFT JOIN A2 ON A1.parentID = A2.id
LEFT JOIN A3 ON A2.parentID = A3.id
WHERE A1.level > A2.level
      AND (A2.level > A3.level OR A3.level IS NULL)
```

Comment: I've writed a shorten query in post, and mistaken only here. But, this example still doesn't work